# DragGesture on Path in ScrollView doesn't work

Tags: swiftui, path, scrollview, gesture

Im working on a macOS app. It should be possible to move Shapes and Lines around in a ScrollView. Moving Shapes like Circle is working. But when I try to move or tap a Path (for drawing a Line), the drag gesture is not working at all.
When the ScrollView is removed, it's possible to move the Path around. But I need it in a ScrollView.
See code below

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var x: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var y: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView( [.vertical, .horizontal])
        {
            ZStack
            {
                Path
                { path in

                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
                }
                .stroke(.blue ,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineCap: .round, dash: []))

                .offset(x: offset.width+x, y: offset.height+y)
                .simultaneousGesture( DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged
                    { gesture in

                        offset = gesture.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded
                    { _ in

                        x += offset.width
                        y += offset.height
                        offset = CGSize.zero
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 800, height: 800)
    }
}
```

When I replace the Path with a circle in the code, everything works fine.

```
Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
```

Replacing simultaneousGesture with gesture or highPriorityGesture doesn't change anything.
Is there a solution to drag a Path within a ScrollView? Or is there another approach to create Lines and drag them around in a ScrollView.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Path's, but if you put `.background(.yellow)` on your path, you can see that it draws a small yellow square at the (0,0) coordinates of your path. And this point you can drag, but only this one. So it should be connected to letting the path start at (0,0) and giving it a `.contentShape` for hit testing.

Comment: Also I read that you should encapsulate `Path`s in a `Shape` struct

Comment: @ChrisR, Thanks for your comments. I'm going to try your suggestions.